# Rekordbox alternative for ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, wine, alternative

There is a programm called "Rekordbox" from Pioneer for Windows. With this tool you can export your songs  to an usb stick and play it with the cd players. When you plug in the stick to the cd players you have a lot of more informations on the little screen rather just copy the files to the usb stick. Since wine doesn't support usb export with Rekordbox, this is pretty useless for me.

Which tool I can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought a Pioneer XDJRR controller with embedded Rekordbox and I feel your pain. I cannot use the PC version to scan all of my tracks and create a metadata file on the USB. Also, the controller only seems to show a waveform when the track has been scanned by Rekordbox (I much prefer using my ears but it still looks cooler than a wall of text.

I have a Linux-friendly workaround that I have been using to make my life easier
My work around is a bit of a hack, and maybe someone with mad coding skills could make a utility that automates the task.

- Install Mixxx open source DJ software on your Linux machine.
- right click on 'Playlists' and select create new; give it a name.
- Drag your tracks into the playlist window.
- Right-click on the playlist name and select 'Analyze entire playlist'. This will get all the BPM counts for you and add it to the playlist window. I've found this to be very accurate.
- Now for the mundane part: Open the actual folder containing all of these tracks and append the BPM count to all of the file names. You might want to keep the rest of the file name tight so you don't have to wait too long for the Pioneer machine to scroll the track title. Whatever works best for you though.
- Another thing that you might want to do is to use Audacity to convert all of your 24bit WAV files to 16bit. I know this sounds like a real cop out, especially if you're an audiophile like me, but for some reason, my Pioneer system doesn't seem to like 24bit files. At the end of the day, 16bit is the resolution found on CDs - still not bad and probably mostly unnoticeable by PA gear or the audience.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rekordbox is proprietary software and the way data is stored is not published as far as I know, so alternative software would have to reverse engineer it.
As you mentioned USB export does not seem to be supported in wine:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26945

A way forward could be to think about a way to workaround it.
So either do a HDD export and see if the data is transferable to USB.
The winehq link has someone asking for help, you can see how far you get.
Another way to walk would be to get wine usb support to the level that the program needs.

Maybe not a direct solution, but the answer to your question about which other tool can be used, I think is "none at the moment".

Comment: The way the data has been stored has been reversed
https://djl-analysis.deepsymmetry.org/djl-analysis/packets.html